# What are minigame ratings used for?

Tags: wii-party-u

After finishing a match of *Wii Party U*, players are asked to rate the previously played board and mini games on a scale of 5 stars.

What are these ratings used for? Do they influence how often certain mini games appear?

[image: “Rate this game” screen]